# Path Intellisense path prompts duplicate files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Why is there two duplicate folders in the pop-up dialog box when you fill in the file path?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMwnj.png)
I think this Path Intellisense is causing the problem，but I don't know how to solve it.
Thank you for your time.

I disable the plugin and it works fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtYJX.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTtrj.png)

Comment: It looks to me like the top one is a class (api) and the bottom one (api.js) is the file, I wouldn't worry about this, looks like it's working fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't have this class，I have one（app.js)  file.

Comment: What is in api.js?